# Google Cloud Pub/Sub to BigQuery template topic subscription

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

When creating a new Dataflow Pub/Sub to BigQuery template it is possible to specify the PubSub `topic`. It appears there is no way to provide the existing PubSub `subscription`, instead Dataflow template creates a new subscription each time it runs.

As far as I understand the PubSub model, the only way to make sure we continue reading the data from the same place in topic is to reuse the same subscription and there seem to be no such option in here.

What will happen when user wants to re-deploy such a Dataflow template? Are we going to lose all the data between the deployments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, the google-provided Pub/Sub to BigQuery template does not support passing a subscription as a parameter ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48216571/9251751)'s an older answer by a googler confirming this). However, it should be easy to edit it so that it does so. You would only need to replace [`getInputTopic`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/templates/PubSubToBigQuery.java#L141) with a `getSubscription` equivalent. In turn, this should be passed to a `PubsubIO.readMessagesWithAttributes().fromSubscription`
`(options.getSubscription())` method (see [here](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.6.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/pubsub/PubsubIO.Read.html#fromSubscription-org.apache.beam.sdk.options.ValueProvider-)) instead of `fromTopic`. After creating your new pipeline, you'd need to create and stage your [template](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/templates/creating-templates#creating-and-staging-templates).

Answer (score 0):

As an update, now there's a new template for this use very use case.

https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-streaming#pubsub-subscription-to-bigquery

```
gcloud dataflow jobs run $jobname \
  --project=$project \
  --disable-public-ips \
  --gcs-location gs://dataflow-templates-$location/latest/PubSub_Subscription_to_BigQuery \
  --worker-machine-type n1-standard-1 \
  --region $location \
  --staging-location gs://$bucket/pss-to-bq \
  --parameters inputSubscription=projects/$project/subscriptions/$subscription,outputTableSpec=$dataset.$table
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).